# Elasticsearch not printing logs when started from commandline with user defined arguments

Tags: elasticsearch

Normally I start elasticsearch using `sudo elasticsearch` which starts printing logs as soon as  press enter but if I give some user-defined configuration like

```
sudo elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=new_cluster -Des.path.conf=/home/cloudera/Documents/es/config/ -Des.path.data=/home/cloudera/Documents/es/data/ -Des.path.log=/home/cloudera/Documents/es/logs/
```

I do not get any output on the console.

Why is it so?

Comment: You have a typo, can you try again with `-Des.path.logs` instead of `-Des.path.log`?

Comment: @Val It gave the following warnings:
`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (node).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`

Comment: Make sure that your `-Des.path.conf` points to a folder where `logging.yml` is also included. Is that the case?